# Remove html5 attributes from input tags of Dom with WTF.quick_form()

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm using the following command to generate forms with WTForms:

```
{{ wtf.quick_form(form)}}
```

I have a number of required fields, however I do not want to use the HTML5 required tag attributes because it results in an ugly style and user experience.

How can I remove the required attributes from my tags on the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use JQuery ?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("form").each(function(){
            $(this).find(':input').each(function(){
                this.removeAttr('required');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```